# Update CredentialCache at runtime

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient, httphandler, .net-8.0, c#-12.0

I'm using DI for an `HttpClient` that uses a `CredentialCache` as it's a linux host that needs to authenticate to a Windows API.  I'm setting the credentials as shown below, which works great.

My issue is that the service account's password is automatically rotated monthly. I can query that new password at runtime using the `IAAM` service that I call below, but I don't know how to replace the credential.

My thought was that when the `HttpClient`'s get/send methods return a 401, then I could grab the new password and update.

But how do I update that credential cache at runtime?

```cs
public static Func<IServiceProvider, SocketsHttpHandler> CreateWindowsAuthHandler(string username, string domain) {
    return x => {
        var pwd = x.GetRequiredService<IAAM>().GetPasswordAsync(username).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        return new SocketsHttpHandler {
            Credentials = new CredentialCache {
                { new(BaseAddress), "Negotiate", new(username, pwd, domain) }
            },
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseProxy = false
        };
    };
}

services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(x => CreateWindowAuthHandler("..", ".."));
```

Comment: I also have similar requirement. Looks like this bug prevents new credentials from being sent with requests when `PreAuthenticate = true`  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93340

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** See this bug preventing `Credential` updates when `PreAuthenticate = true` https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93340

One possible way is to use `DelegatingHandler` to override the `CredentialsCache` from the `base.InnerHandler` property which seems a bit dirty (assumes that innerHandler will always be SocketsHttpHandler).

```cs
public class OverridingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (base.InnerHandler is SocketsHttpHandler socketsHttpHandler)
        {
            CredentialCache newCredentials = GetCredentials();
            socketsHttpHandler.Credentials = newCredentials;
        }
        
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and then do

```cs
 services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(new OverridingHandler());
```

Perhaps a better way is to create your own implementation of the `ICredentials` interface that can handle credential updates.

I saw an example implementation in this bug report  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93340 called `CredentialPlugin`.

Hopefully .NET team will provide a extensability point or add async methods on `ICredentials` to for updating credentials dynamically

Comment: Here is an actual implementation of `ICredentials` in the Nuget repo. https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Configuration/Proxy/IProxyCredentialCache.cs